# Transparency and Html Objects (IE7-8)

Tags: html, object

Having issues with applying transparency to Html object background in IE7-8.  I've tried adding `zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=50); opacity: 0.5;` to the `<object>` as well as the `<body>` of the child page.  Both methods add transparency to both background/text and white background in IE7-8 is still there.  Is there a way to have an Html object's background 100% transparent in earlier versions of IE without effecting text?

Parent:

```
<style type="text/css">
.object {
    position:relative;
    width:870px;
    height:500px;
}
</style>

<div id="wrap">
<object class="object" type="text/html" data="path/to/child"></object>
</div>
```

Child:

```
<style type="text/css">
.body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

<HTML>
<body>

<div id="content">

<!--Content for Html Object-->

</div>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: Updated op, can't apply transparency directly to the object background, any suggestions?

Comment: what are you actually putting in the `<object>`? html?

Comment: @Joseph, the object is referencing the child page with content in plain text/html, no swf or images.  I avoided using an iframe for unrelated reasons.

Comment: Embedding an SVG file using the <object> with transparent background would solve this, not sure if there's a method for plain text/html.

Comment: You could add a absolute position DIV as a sibling element to your text and change the transparency of that. As far as I know, setting transparency on the parent element affects all it's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might wanna try this since the child of the object is an `<HTML>`, this might work. place this css in the parent html.

```
.object html{
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); 
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

this is taken from jsfiddle so ignore the iframe up top.

[image]

Comment: I eventually wound up using a transparent png for the background and brought everything into the object, then embedded the object in a php file included once in the parent page.  Haven't the slightest clue why but it seems to fix transparency issues in IE when embedding entire html pages.